# Не работает spring.datasource.data

Tags: spring-boot, properties

Пытаюсь запустить SQL скрипт, указав настройки в .properties
Но, spring.datasource.data не работает. Перечитал множество источников, но так и не нашёл ответ.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите понять, почему оно не работает?